# Получить местоположение процесса по его ID

Tags: c++, c, winapi, процесс

Необходимо получить список запущенных процессов, а также вывести полный путь к исполняемому файлу. При обращении к некоторым системным процессам получаю ошибку #5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (Access is denied).
Пробовал устанавливать привилегии, но это ни к чему не привело. В чем может быть ошибка?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>
using namespace std;

BOOL SetPrivilege(
    HANDLE hToken,          // access token handle
    LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege,  // name of privilege to enable/disable
    BOOL bEnablePrivilege   // to enable or disable privilege
)
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(
        NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
        lpszPrivilege,   // privilege to lookup
        &luid))        // receives LUID of privilege
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege)
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    else
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    // Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, (PDWORD)NULL))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    HANDLE hToken;
    HANDLE snapshot;
    TCHAR filename[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD charsCarried = MAX_PATH;
    PROCESSENTRY32 process;
    int count = 0;

    snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    process.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    if (snapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (Process32First(snapshot, &process))
        {
            do
            {
                count++;
                OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);
                SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE);
                hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, process.th32ProcessID);

                if (hProcess != NULL)
                {
                GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, filename, MAX_PATH);
                printf("%d - PID: %d, Name: %ls, CountThread: %d\n",
                    count,
                    process.th32ProcessID,
                    filename,
                    process.cntThreads);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Err: %d\n", GetLastError());
                }
                SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, FALSE);
            } 
            while (Process32Next(snapshot, &process));
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    CloseHandle(snapshot);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваша программа запускается от имени администратора?

Comment: @Arhad Да, сама VS и в свойствах проекта (Linker -> Manifest File -> UAC Execution Level - Administrator).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать функцию [QueryFullProcessImageName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx). Она позволяет получить расположение файла для всех процессов, в том числе системных или другого пользователя (при наличии привилегий администратора), а также 64-разрядных процессов из 32-разрядного приложения.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>    

void ErrorMes(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message 

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    wprintf(L"%s failed with error %d: %s", 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);     

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);

}


int main()
{
    HANDLE hProcess=NULL;
    HANDLE hToken;
    HANDLE snapshot;
    TCHAR filename[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD charsCarried = MAX_PATH;
    PROCESSENTRY32 process;
    int count = 0;

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

    snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    process.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    if (snapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (Process32First(snapshot, &process))
        {
            do
            {
                wprintf(L"PID: %d, Name: %s, CountThreads: %d\n",                    
                    process.th32ProcessID,
                    process.szExeFile,
                    process.cntThreads);                                

                /*get process handle*/
                hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, process.th32ProcessID);
                if(hProcess==NULL){
                    ErrorMes(L"OpenProcess");
                    wprintf(L"\n");
                    continue;
                }

                charsCarried=MAX_PATH;

                /* get executable name*/
                if(QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess,0,filename,&charsCarried)!=FALSE)
                {
                    wprintf(L"%s\n",                    
                    filename);
                }
                else
                {
                    ErrorMes(L"QueryFullProcessImageName");
                    wprintf(L"\n");
                }
                wprintf(L"\n");

                CloseHandle(hProcess);  
                hProcess = NULL;
            } 
            while (Process32Next(snapshot, &process));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMes(L"CreateToolhelp32Snapshot");
    }

    if(hProcess!=NULL)CloseHandle(hProcess);
    CloseHandle(snapshot);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```